# Multiprocess inside a multiprocess

Tags: python, multiprocessing

eg.
I have a controller script.
I have a worker script.
I have 50 python objects that have to be passed to the worker script.
I want them to run in parallel.

The worker script has its own parallelisation of some database fetches.
This i achieve by:

```
p = Pool(processes=NUM_PROCS)
results = p.starmap(db_fetch, db_fetch_arguments)
p.close()
p.join()
```

Whats the most pythonic way, i can pass my 50 arguments (python objects, not string arguments), into my worker and make it run in parallel, and not have any issues when the worker tries to spawn more child processes.

Thankyou in advance.

Edit 1:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

def worker(num:int):
    num_list = list(range(num))
    # print('worker start')
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(printer, num_list)


def printer(num:int):
    # print('printer')
    print(f"Printing num {num} - child: {os.getpid()} - parent: {os.getppid()}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(4) as controller_pool:
        controller_pool.map(worker, [1,2,3])

print('here')
```

Here I am getting the error: AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children

Comment: I think in that case better store the objects in shared memory, rather that passing them around through Pipes and Queues.

Comment: I could do that. Okay. So what if nothing had to be passed? And i want a child process to start another multiprocess pool.

Comment: You only have to pass a reference to the object holding the shared memory objects. This reference is handed over to all sub_processes and they can work on the data objects

Comment: Are these 50 objects you are referring to `db_fetch_arguments` or something else and what type of objects are they and what are you doing to them? What issues are you concerned with? This is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and I don't know how anyone can answer this without more details.

Comment: Thankyou for pointing that out to me. Let me make an edit and clear it out.

Comment: @Nechoj - i used the ProcessPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures to have as my controller outer pool. Inside I've used normal multiprocessing.Pool

Answer (score 0):

Used the ProcessPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures to have as my controller outer pool. Inside I've used normal multiprocessing.Pool

Thanks.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import os

def worker(num:int):
    num_list = list(range(num))
    # print('worker start')
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(printer, num_list)


def printer(num:int):
    # print('printer')
    print(f"Printing num {num} - child: {os.getpid()} - parent: {os.getppid()}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as controller_pool:
        controller_pool.map(worker, [1,2,3])

print('here')
```